# Using aggregate function to calculate unique totals

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm having issue being able to calculate the sum of unique Breeding Code's Plantings and Death Count. I'm trying to use aggregate function to do this.

```
Goal:

##      rowBrCrCode rowPlanted rowPsaDeath rowSurvival
##   1:      GL_287         63          24           0
##   2:      GL_287         13           7           0
##   3:      GL_287         67          26           0
##   4:     aCK_227         17           5           0
##   5:     aCK_406         20           1           0

into

##      rowBrCrCode rowPlanted rowPsaDeath rowSurvival
##   1:      GL_287        143          57           0
##   2:     aCK_227         17           5           0
##   3:     aCK_406         20           1           0
```

rowSurvival will be calculated after this function.

Current code is enter code here this, problematic code is commented out (I am writing in R):

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
test <- fread(file.choose(), header = TRUE, data.table = TRUE)
testRowLength <- nrow(test)
rowBrCrCode <- ""
rowPlanted <- 0
rowPsaDeath <- 0
rowSurvival <- 0
for(i in 1:testRowLength){
  if(test$BrCrCode[i] == ""){
    test$BrCrCode[i] <- paste("PH_", i, sep = "")
    print(paste("hit found, turned nothing into ", test$BrCrCode[i], sep = ""))
  }
  slashCount <- str_count(test$BrCrCode[i], '/')
  if(slashCount == 1){
    print(paste("hit found, turn ", test$BrCrCode[i], " into ", unlist(strsplit(test$BrCrCode[i], split = '/', fixed=TRUE))[1], sep = ""))
    test$BrCrCode[i] <- unlist(strsplit(test$BrCrCode[i], split = '/', fixed=TRUE))[1]
  }
  else if(slashCount > 1){
    print(paste("control found, value ", test$BrCrCode[i], " into ", paste("control_", unlist(strsplit(test$BrCrCode[i], split = '/', fixed=TRUE))[1], sep = ""), sep = ""))
    test$BrCrCode[i] <- paste("control_", unlist(strsplit(test$BrCrCode[i], split = '/', fixed=TRUE))[1], sep = "")
  }
  rowBrCrCode[i] <- test$BrCrCode[i]
  rowPlanted[i] <- test$Planted[i]
  rowPsaDeath[i] <- test$PsaDeath[i]
}
firstDT <- data.table(rowBrCrCode, rowPlanted, rowPsaDeath, rowSurvival)
print(firstDT)
#firstDT_agg <- aggregate(x = firstDT, by = list(rowPlanted, rowPsaDeath), FUN = "sum")
```

Comment: Has confirmed that both ways work, but only after some variables in the data.table were converted upon entry as numeric. For whatever reason, when you add numbers into a vector, it changes to character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just this if all you want to do is aggregate-

```
test2 <- aggregate(cbind(rowPlanted, rowPsaDeath, rowSurvival) ~ BrCrCode,
                   data = test, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: If you are importing you firstDT data from a file, pre-define the column classes. If you are creating it within a program, make sure the columns are numeric. For now, you can use firstDT[,2:4] <- as.numeric( firstDT[,2:4]) and then run above code

Comment: It was being defined at this line. `firstDT <- data.table(rowBrCrCode, rowPlanted, rowPsaDeath, rowSurvival)`. Just realised I like this one better, it sorts the types of cross code by alphabetical order

Answer (score 1):

The dataset seems to be a `data.table`, so we can the `data.table` methods.  Grouped by 'rowBrCrCode', we loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and get the `sum`.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = rowBrCrCode]
#       rowBrCrCode rowPlanted rowPsaDeath rowSurvival
#1:      GL_287        143          57           0
#2:     aCK_227         17           5           0
#3:     aCK_406         20           1           0
```